# Have any novel virus or bacteria ever been created by man in the laboratory that we know of?

Tags: virus, bacteria, medical-history

This question may be off topic for medicine. Let us not consider COVID19. Are there any known man made viruse or  bacteria ever created or modified by man that we know of?

Bio weapons labs weaponize know biological bacteria or virus but maybe  that means nothing more than delivery. Maybe everything the weapons labs have was first made by nature but I do not know that is why I am asking.

Comment: +1 for a balanced question on weaponization of pathogens. The World Health Organization lists [diseases associated with biological weapons](https://www.who.int/csr/delibepidemics/disease/en/) and the CDC mentioned [most likely pathogens](https://www.cdc.gov/anthrax/bioterrorism/threat.html) but I don't know of pathogens specifically engineered for the purpose

Comment: @Chris Rogers Thank you Chris that answers my question very nicely. Well then if COVID was something that was "tweaked" from some  coronavirus then it would be a first in the creation of a new type of virus.But from what I read there is no proof of this as of now. Thank you

Comment: [Yes, there certainly are!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetically_modified_virus) Viruses are commonly used as vectors for scientific study (basically they are a good and efficient way to alter genes in a species to find out the effect of the gene) and they are edited by humans. We do not make them from scratch, but we do change them sufficiently. I don’t know if this is sufficient to call them novel. // Of course, such viruses (should) posses no threat to humanity, they are uncontagious. And they are not created with the intent to infect either.

Comment: @Narusan Thank you for clarifying that. Yes I knew  about the editing...so I guess you raise a good point of what is considered novel. I guess we could  to stick with the list from the above link provided by Chris Rogers.